# How to get post value as array from form created using loop in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, loops, post

I need to get post value as array from form created using for loop ,

Here is my view

```
   <?php for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {?>
            <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input name="<?php echo 'fname'.$i?>" class="form-control" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Surname</label>
                    <input  name="<?php echo 'sname'.$i?>" class="form-control" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Date of Birth</label>
                    <input name="<?php echo 'dob'.$i?>" class="date-pick-years form-control" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php }?>

        <input type="submit" />
```

How to get these post value in controller , i need as a array for example i value is 2 means i need my output as

```
    $array1=array('name'=>$this->input->post('name0')),'sname'=>$this->input->post('sname0')),'dob'=>$this->input->post('dob0'))

   $array2=array('name'=>$this->input->post('name1')),'sname'=>$this->input->post('sname1')),'dob'=>$this->input->post('dob1'))

Total array =array($array1,$array2);
```

How to get this in a loop in controller to get required output First array value as first loop second array value as 2nd loop ...etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just have changed the names of your inputs:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
 <?php for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {?>
            <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name</label> <input
                    name="<?php echo 'people['.$i.'][fname]'?>" class="form-control"
                    type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Surname</label> <input
                    name="<?php echo 'people['.$i.'][sname]'?>" class="form-control"
                    type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Date of Birth</label> <input
                    name="<?php echo 'people['.$i.'][dob]'?>"
                    class="date-pick-years form-control" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <?php }?>

        <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The result $_POST array after submit form is:

```
array(1) {
  ["people"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["fname"]=>
      string(5) "James"
      ["sname"]=>
      string(4) "Bond"
      ["dob"]=>
      string(10) "22.01.1950"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["fname"]=>
      string(4) "Jack"
      ["sname"]=>
      string(6) "Sparow"
      ["dob"]=>
      string(10) "08.05.1970"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(3) {
      ["fname"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["sname"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["dob"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    [3]=>
    array(3) {
      ["fname"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["sname"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["dob"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    [4]=>
    array(3) {
      ["fname"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["sname"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["dob"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can loop in your controller using:

```
$arr_res = $_POST['people']
```

or your wrapper(I'm not sure)

$arr_res = $this->input->post('people');

I hope this helps.

Good practice: don't use the same name vars as function names(particulary in php) - $array = array(...) etc. better use e.g. $arr_res (array with results) or $people, $people_arr.